# Form.serialize() seems to return null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to post a form to the controller in which the controller accepts a FormCollection as a parameter.  When I try to access an item within the dsCollection I get null.  The only items within the FormCollection is `"__RequestVerificationToken"` and `"dsCollection"`.  Another thing is I am generating my forms HTML dynamically using javascript and assigning values to them at the same time.

Here is my ajax to post data to serverside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#postEditDatasource').click(function (event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(deletedDatapoints));
    //serialise and assign json data to hidden field
    $('#dsDeletedDP').val(JSON.stringify(deletedDatapoints));

    //anti forgery token
    //get the form
    var form = $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm');
    //from the form get the antiforgerytoken
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

    var URL = '/Settings/EditDatasource';
    console.log(form);
    //we make an ajax call to the controller on click
    //because the controller has a AntiForgeryToken attribute
    //we need to get the token from the form and pass it with the ajax call.
    $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').on('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                dsCollection: form.serialize()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                alert('this worked')
                if (data.result == "Error") {
                    ShowDatasourcePostAlert('failPost', 3000);
                } else {
                    ShowDatasourcePostAlert('successPost', 3000);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + ', ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
});
})
```

and here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditDatasource(FormCollection dsCollection)
    {
        var devName = dsCollection["deviceName"];
            //LoadDataToViewModel();

            //Get the name of the device in which we will pass it to the XML edit helper 
            //In order for us to locate the
            //var getEditDatasource = Convert.ToString((from ds in dsVM.devices
            //                         where ds.deviceID == Convert.ToInt64(dsCollection["dsID"])
            //                         select ds.deviceName));


            return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

and here is a snippet of my HTML,  I have too many controls but they pretty much follow the same formatting.

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="deviceName">Device Name: </label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="deviceName" class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Device name is required" name="deviceName" value="TestName">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="deviceDisplay">Displayed As: </label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input id="deviceDisplay" class="form-control" type="text" data-val="false" data-val-required="Device name is required" name="deviceDisplay" value="testDisplay">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="deviceDesc">Description: </label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<textarea id="deviceDesc" class="form-control" data-val="false" name="deviceDesc">Test desc</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

If I use serializeArray() it gives me back 31 entries however the entries are `"dsCollection[0][name]" "dsCollection[0][value]"` with the index going all the way up to 30

Comment: Have you tried: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: You have a line that said console.log(form); is this result null?

Comment: @Luis.Andrade no it is not null

Comment: @Johnathon64 Yeah, something is happening I'm not sure what is it, I'm not an expert but I try to help. I recomend you to use this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) helper  because if you have a model it will write for you the ajax call and I think that you could send the token as a parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`serialize` method transform your `form` fields in a query string so you should just append the token to that string instead of creating another object.

If you inspect your request today you'll see that you're posting a value like this:

```
_RequestVerificationToken=token&dsCollection=deviceDesc%3Dcontent1%26deviceDisplay%3Dcontent2
```

When you have an antifogery token in a standard form, token data is sent alongside other input data (because actually it's just an hidden input) so the correct way to send it would be:

```
deviceDesc=content1&deviceDisplay=content2&_RequestVerificationToken=token
```

Other thing is, it looks like your anti forgery token is already inside your `form` so you do not need to do anything else than just `form.serialize`.

You can do the following in your javascript code:

```
data: form.serialize()
```

Comment: does serialize also include hidden input fields?  In my collection they do not seem to be included when I step through my C# code